# Загрузка изображения или видео по пользовательской ссылке

Tags: reactjs, cors

Передо мной стоит задача дать пользователю несколько способов загрузки файла через интерфейс: drag-and-drop, upload from files и upload by url. Первые два я уже сделал, но с третьим впал в ступор, потому как любые попытки получить файл с того же Google или Яндекс присекаются политикой CORS, и дальше запроса "method: OPTIONS" дело не доходит (No Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

Ниже прикладываю скрин интерфейса с выделенным полем, в которое пользователь должен вставить ссылку на файл, после чего успешно этот файл отправить.

Буду благодарен за любые идеи.

Да, пишу на Реакте

[image: Скриншот интерфейса]

Answer (score 0):

Если вы пытаетесь загрузить файл с этой страницы с помощью `XMLHttpRequest`,
то вы обязательно столкнетесь с CORS.

Google или Яндекс имеют специальное API, а с другими сайтами ничего не выйдет.

Что бы обойти это, делается запрос к своему серверу с указанием ссылки на необходимый файл, и уже средствами сервера загружать его без ограничений CORS.